# Which IoC containers support returning specific objects based on identifiers?

Tags: c#, mvvm, ioc-container

I'm just now beginning to experiment with IoC containers.  Currently, I'm using a home-grown factory to build my ViewModels, which come in two flavors: singleton, and id-based.  In other words, my application (by definition) only has one Room at a time, and hence only one RoomViewModel, but many users can be in that room, so I need many UserViewModels.  But I want to make sure that, say, for the User with UserId="johnsmith", only one UserViewModel is ever created, and any attempt to retrieve that UserViewModel will return the same instance.

I don't know if it will help explain things or confuse them, but this is the method that I'm currently using to do this:

```
public ViewModelType GetViewModelByKey<ViewModelType, KeyType>(KeyType key) 
        where ViewModelType : AlantaViewModelBase, new()
    {
        IDictionary dictionary;
        var type = typeof(ViewModelType);
        if (!keyedViewModelDictionaries.TryGetValue(type, out dictionary))
        {
            dictionary = new Dictionary<KeyType, ViewModelType>();
            keyedViewModelDictionaries.Add(type, dictionary);
        }
        var viewModels = (Dictionary<KeyType, ViewModelType>)dictionary;
        ViewModelType vm;
        if (!viewModels.TryGetValue(key, out vm))
        {
            vm = new ViewModelType();
            viewModels.Add(key, vm);
            vm.Initialize(this);
        }
        return vm;
    }
```

This means that these two calls will return separate instances:

```
// Get VM for user.UserId="john";
var userVM1 = viewModelFactory.GetViewModelByKey<UserViewModel, string>("john");
// Get VM for user.UserId="suzie";
var userVM2 = viewModelFactory.GetViewModelByKey<UserViewModel, string>("suzie");
```

But these will return the same instance:

```
// Get the same VM for user.UserId="bob";
var userVM1 = viewModelFactory.GetViewModelByKey<UserViewModel, string>("bob");
var userVM2 = viewModelFactory.GetViewModelByKey<UserViewModel, string>("bob");
```

The ability to do this solves a heck of a lot of data-binding and synchronization problems, so it's not a pattern that I'm going to give up on easily.

But I'd like, if possible, to move to a standard IoC container, since presumably they have more features, don't require specific types, and are certainly more standardized.  But in reading up on them, I haven't come across any obvious indication that they support my second sort of approach.  In other words, they all support the standard two lifestyles (singleton and transient), but I want something a little different: singleton per object identity.  Do the standard IoC containers support this? How? Which ones?

Sorry if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEF supports this via [Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833299.aspx) using a "Contract Name".  This allows you to export and import with contract names specified:

```
[Import("bob", typeof(UserViewModel)]
public UserViewModel bobViewModel { get; set; }
```

**Edited by Ken Smith**
See the discussion below for our eventual conclusion that the IoC containers don't support this sort of behavior out of the box, and perhaps aren't really designed to solve this problem.

Comment: Does that allow me to specify *at runtime* that I want this UserViewModel to be for "Bob" (rather than at design time)?  Nothing that I've read so far in the documentation on the MEF Export/Import attributes has led me to believe that, but I could very well be wrong.

Comment: The difference between "Bob" and "Fred" is that they're different users.  In other words, a web service will at various points return a number of different instances of User objects, some with UserId="Bob", some with UserId="John", etc.  I need to wrap those User objects with a UserViewModel, but I only want to create one UserViewModel for each user, even though (at various times) the web service might return different User objects for the same (real-world) user.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ken: Sort of - Personally, wrapping a new VM around the user is probably a hell of a lot easier than trying to work this out this way.  Otherwise, I'd just import a factory to create your VM, and store results in a dictionary yourself.

Comment: The issue is that I've got a bunch of stuff (event handlers, data bindings, etc.) already wired up to the existing VM.  So if an updated Model comes in from the (duplex) web service, it solves a whole lot of headaches if I can just update the Model property of the existing VM, without creating a new instance.  And I am doing the Dictionary of Dictionaries thing now (as you can see in the code sample above), I was just wondering if this is the sort of problem that IoC containers are supposed to solve. Beginning to sound like it isn't.

Comment: @Ken: Yeah, the IoC containers aren't really oriented towards this problem, but rather discoverability and types.  They're great at inserting a requirement, but not managing lifetime of your normal types, esp. multiple instances of a single type, which is what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know.  Sounds like there isn't some obviously better way to do what I need.  Marking this discussion as the answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

Spring.NET certainly supports non-singleton named objects.  Singleton is the default DI behavior, but you can also specify that individual instances be created as well.

See the documentation [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-scopes).

Comment: I presume you're talking about the "prototype" scope? If so, I don't think that's what I'm looking for, unless there's something in the docs I'm just missing.  I specifically don't want a new instance to be created every time I call `context.GetObject("UserViewModel")`. The syntax I'm thinking would be more like `context.GetObject<UserViewModel>(uvm => uvm.UserId = 'Bob')`.

Comment: Ah - my mistake, then.  I'm not aware of such a built-in capability in Spring.NET - you'd have to code your own data structure, or your own object scope (egads).